# #[message] vs #[payload] in mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I could see two different objects - message and payload in Mule Esb. But I am not able to understand the actual characteristics of the both. Could anyone kindly help me to understand this?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mule message, `#[message]` is the data that passes through an application via one or more flows. It consists of two main parts:

- The message **header**, which contains metadata about the message.
- The message **payload**, which contains your business-specific data.

And The message payload `#[payload]` is the most important part of the Mule message which contains the data your Mule application processes.

Please refer [Mule Documentaion](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/mule-message-structure) for more details.